# How is the best way to have a one-to-many relationship with an arbitrary number of fields in an apache derby database?

Tags: java, sql, database, data-structures, derby

I am making an application for a campground that has a list of camping sites, each of which has a list of reservations. There can be any number of reservations for each camping site and any number of camping sites.

I started off by just storing this data in a csv and using that to handle everything. This is working really well because after a few columns of identifying information for each site, I just have an arbitrary number of reservations that I can go through. It's also really easy for me to add a new site if I want to add that functionality to my application since I can just add a new line and leave the reservation part blank if there aren't any reservations.

I'm thinking that I should instead use a database to store this information for the following reasons:

1. I need to be able to search and modify specific sites in addition to just iterating through them in order. With the CSV solution, iterating through them in order has been great when I need to use them all but I don't want to have to iterate through to find a specific reservation. Plus modifying the csv isn't looking to be that great either.
2. I am hoping to gain a better understanding of databases in general and I don't believe using a csv is the most professional way to do this, nor would it be the best practice.

How exactly could I do this? If, for example, I had only one camping site then I would just add another table that represents the reservations as an entry to the table but since I have at least 100 camping sites and can have an arbitrary amount, this doesn't seem to make sense. Am I just not understanding something or am I correct in coming to that conclusion?

Some more information:

- Since I haven't said it yet, this is a java application with an apache derby database.
- This project is not for a class or a job, I'm just trying to practice my programming skills and help someone out who runs a campground at the same time.

Comment: At a high level from a database perspective, sounds like you need a `camping_sites` table and a `reservations` table. Each of those tables can hold multiple rows.

Comment: The Wikipedia article, [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) might be of some help.

Comment: @ZackMacomber I was thinking this could be a possibility but I'm not sure what the primary key would be for the reservations table. A reservation starts at a specific date and on a specific site but there can be multiple reservations at a specific site and different dates and multiple reservations at different sites but with the same date. Because of this, I'd need a separate table for each site that holds each reservation. That seems pretty ridiculous, especially with over 100 sites. Is there another option?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thank you! I took a look and although I've heard about the idea of normalization, I've never read about it. It seems as though just storing a list of reservations in a certain column would be "illegal" as others have said.

Comment: @JacobBernard Oftentimes, a database table will have an `id` as a primary key and `unique` constraints. Sounds like to me your `reservations` table could have an `id` as the primary key and the combination of `start_date` and `site_id` as a `unique` constraint. Oftentimes the `id` on a table just auto increments when a new row is put in.